# python shift function does not work as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I have a data frame for the page events with the following structure:

- sessionId - unique session id
- event_date - date and time where the event occurred
- pageTitle - event name (page to which users navigated)

In order to see, how users navigate in app and build a Sankey chart for it, I would like to create a new column "next event" which would be recording the next event for the session using the shift function, but the code below returns NAN values or mixing everything and display wrong next event (I see it from event_date).

```
df['event_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_date'], unit='s')
df.sort_values(['sessionId', 'pageTitle', 'event_date'],
                 ascending=[True, False, True], inplace=True)


grouped = df.groupby('sessionId')

def get_next_event(x): return x['pageTitle'].shift(-1)

df["next_event"] = grouped.apply(
    lambda x: get_next_event(x)).reset_index(0, drop=True)

display(df.query('sessionId =="1"').sort_values('event_date'))
display(df.query('sessionId =="2"').sort_values('event_date'))
```

**results example**

| sessionId | event_date | pageTitle | next_event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-26 19:23:45.820 | Search | Search |
| 1 | 2021-05-26 19:23:50.074 | Statement | Statement |
| 1 | 2021-05-26 19:30:06.086 | Search | Search |
| 1 | 2021-05-26 19:30:09.995 | Statement | Statement |
| 1 | 2021-05-26 19:47:24.058 | Statement | Statement |
| 1 | 2021-05-26 19:57:31.661 | Aging Report | NAN |
| 1 | 2021-05-26 19:57:40.672 | Search | Aging Report |
| 1 | 2021-05-26 19:57:44.160 | Statement | Search |

2nd

| sessionId | event_date | pageTitle | next_event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-07-20 15:43:35.941 | Aging Report | NaN |
| 2 | 2021-07-20 15:44:52.739 | Search | Search |
| 2 | 2021-07-20 15:44:56.173 | Statement | Statement |
| 2 | 2021-07-20 16:23:02.761 | Statement | Statement |

Please help to understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: FYI: `lambda x: get_next_event(x)` is the same as just `get_next_event`. No need for the lambda.

Comment: Find out the solution. I simply need to do it as following:
df["next_event"] = df['pageTitle'].shift(-1)